Error in Firebase Deploy Due to ESLint Issues and Lint Command Execution Fails (ENOENT)
I’m facing a problem while deploying my Firebase project. After running the firebase deploy command from the root of my project, I encountered a significant number of ESLint errors and the deployment failed with the following error message:
Additionally, my ESLint output lists multiple problems such as:
Object Curly Spacing: There should be no space after '{' or There should be no space before '}'
Line Length: This line has a length of 208. Maximum allowed is 80
Indentation Issues: Expected indentation of X spaces but found Y
Trailing Comma: Missing trailing comma
Questions:

Why is the lint command being invoked during deployment, and how can
I bypass or fix this?
How can I fix the ENOENT error related to
%RESOURCE_DIR%?
What’s the best way to address these linting issues
across multiple files efficiently?
Should I reconfigure Firebase or
ESLint to handle this issue better?

Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!


